# Opencv PNP in a Corridor

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration, 3d-reconstruction

I have reconstructed two frames using 5-point essential matrix, for sequential frames I am using PNP to get the camera pose before reconstructing the matches.

When I use video frames progressing through a corridor the results of PNP are terrible?

Is this a degenerate case?

Comment: Example images may help.

Comment: 1- You should use PnP with RANSAC.  2- How do you get 3D points for PnP from a mono camera? 3- Do you have sufficient baseline?